# Which method is better for combining multiple lists without duplicates?

Tags: python

Given a social network, I'm returning a list of friends of friends connections. For example, if A -> B and B -> [C, D] , then fxn(A) = [C, D]

Given I already collected a list ([B,...,n]) of friends of user A using a function called "get_connections" (literally just returns a list of friends of a given user). The original method I utilized to conduct this procedure uses two For loops:

```
return_list = []

for friend in friends_list:
    second_friends_list = get_connections(network, friend)

    # Go through each friend's friend list
    for friends in second_friends_list:
        # Check for duplicates
        if friends not in return_list:
            return_list.append(friends)

return return_list
```

The second method I identified through Stackoverflow is the following:

```
for friends in friends_list:
    return_list = list(set(return_list) | set(get_connections(network, friends)))
```

Is there a significant difference between these two methods? My knowledge of algorithm is very limited, and I understand that the for loop method is O^2, but I do not know how set works exactly to better assess its advantage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set will do this about as well as you can -- Using a `list` is particularly bad here as membership testing (`in` operator) happens in O(N) (you have to look at every element until you find the one you're looking for).  Assuming the friends in the friend list are hashible:

```
>>> class Friend(object):
...   def __init__(self, friend_list):
...     self.friend_list = list(friend_list)
... 
>>> f1 = Friend('ABCD')
>>> f2 = Friend('CDEF')
>>> f3 = Friend('AGHIJKLMN')
>>> my_friends = [f1, f2, f3]
>>> set().union(*(f.friend_list for f in my_friends))
set(['A', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'D', 'G', 'F', 'I', 'H', 'K', 'J', 'M', 'L', 'N'])
```

Here's a little demo where I've used `set.union` rather than the union operator (`|`).  The difference is that the method version will accept non-set arguments so you can avoid iterating over the collection twice.  If you'd rather, we can also do this using the regular `set` constructor and `itertools`<sup>1</sup>:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> all_friends = itertools.chain.from_iterable(f.friend_list for f in my_friends)
>>> set(all_friends)
set(['A', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'D', 'G', 'F', 'I', 'H', 'K', 'J', 'M', 'L', 'N'])
```

Both of these operate in O(M) operations (where M is the total number or "friends" in all the friend lists).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>... Or a nested comprehension -- But I've never been a fan of those ...</sup>

Comment: This is definitely helpful insight. If you don't mind, can you expand on the following line: set().union(*(f.friend_list for f in my_friends)). I understand the set().union part, but what's the purpose of the asterisk?

Comment: @AdibBehjat -- I'm [unpacking the argument list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).  In other words, it is the same as if I called `set().union(f1.friend_list, f2.friend_list, f3.friend_list)`

Comment: Nice to know! That's definitely helpful. What are your thoughts about this: return_list = list(set().union(*(get_connections(network,f) for f in friends_list))) - Would this still satisfy the O(M) condition?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the time complexity of `friends_list` function is `0(n^3)` as it also looks up `friends` in `return_list` which takes an extra `0(n)` in addition to those two `for` loops.

Converting the inner lists to `set` will cause function to run in linear time `0(n)`.